# How to replace lines from one file to another file

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a one file like below and required to grep the lines which are starting with system_props(^system_props).

```
JAVA_HOME=`find "$AGENT_HOME/jre" -name release -type f 2>/dev/null | sed "s|/release||g"`

system_props="$system_props -sensu.controller.hostName=abc.nam.net"
system_props="$system_props -sensu.controller.port=8181"
system_props="$system_props -sensu.controller.node=Mcagent"

if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
   if [ -d "/opt/middleware" ]; then
      JAVA_HOME=`find /opt/middleware -type d -name jre 2>/dev/null | grep WebSphere | grep java | grep -v grep | sort | uniq`
   fi
fi
```

I have another file called as file2 which having dummy content like below.

```
JAVA_HOME=`find "$AGENT_HOME/jre" -name release -type f 2>/dev/null | sed "s|/release||g"`

system_props="$system_props -sensu.controller.hostName=testhost.net"
system_props="$system_props -sensu.controller.port=8080"

if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
   if [ -d "/opt/middleware" ]; then
      JAVA_HOME=`find /opt/middleware -type d -name jre 2>/dev/null | grep WebSphere | grep java | grep -v grep | sort | uniq`
   fi
fi
```

Now my requirement is to replace the content of `cat file1 | grep ^system_props` to `cat file2 | grep ^system_props)`

the expected output of both system_props values should be same and append missing lines from file1

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and expected output more clearly, as it is not clear as of now. Kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: You mean to say `system_props` right? Could you please confirm as your samples have only this keyword in them.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, yes I mean to say "system_props".. it was typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has changed requirement a bit so adding edited solution here.

```
awk  '
FNR==NR{
  if(match($0,/^system_props=".*/)){
    a[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+14,RLENGTH-14)
  }
  next
}
match($0,/^system_props="/){
  $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) a[++count1]
}
1;
 END{
  if(count!=count1){
    while(++count1<=count){
      print a[count1]
    }
  }
}
' File2 File1
```

---

---

Could you please try following. This is going to substitute values from 1 file to another file by string `system_props` occurrence., means 1st occurrence of string from File2 will be placed in first occurrence of string in File1.

```
awk  '
FNR==NR{
  if(match($0,/^system_props=".*/)){
    a[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+14,RLENGTH-14)
  }
  next
}
match($0,/^system_props="/){
  $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) a[++count1]
}
1
'   Input_file2  Input_file1
```

For your shown samples output will be as follows.

```
JAVA_HOME=`find "$AGENT_HOME/jre" -name release -type f 2>/dev/null | sed "s|/release||g"`

system_props="$system_props -sensu.controller.hostName=testhost.net"
system_props="$system_props -sensu.controller.port=8080"

if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
   if [ -d "/opt/middleware" ]; then
      JAVA_HOME=`find /opt/middleware -type d -name jre 2>/dev/null | grep WebSphere | grep java | grep -v grep | sort | uniq`
   fi
fi
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk  '                                            ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                          ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file2 is being read.
  if(match($0,/^system_props=".*/)){              ##Checking condition if line has system_props=" then do following.
    a[++count]=substr($0,RSTART+14,RLENGTH-14)    ##Creating array a with index variable count(whose value is increasing with 1) and its value is substring of current line with starting point of RSTART and ending point of RLENGTH.
  }
  next                                            ##next will skip all further lines from here.
}
match($0,/^system_props="/){                      ##Checking condition if a line starts from
  $0=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) a[++count1]        ##Assigning substring of current line from RSTART to RLENGTH and putting value of array a which we collected from previous file.
}
1                                                 ##1 will print edited/non-edited lines of Input_file1 here.
'  File2 File1                                    ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```